# KDB : Inappropriate type casting for aggregation query result

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, kdb

I ran the following query in KDB to create the table strucrute and insert data in it :-

```
n:1000000;item:`apple`banana`orange`pear;city:`beijing`chicago`london`paris;tab:([]time:asc n?0D0;n?item;amount:n?100;n?city);
```

Post which, I ran a Java program to make a select query with aggregation. The code is as follows :-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import kx.c;

public class Aggregate {

    public static class KxTableModel {
        private c.Flip flip;
        public void setFlip(c.Flip data) {
            this.flip = data;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return Array.getLength(flip.y[0]);
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return flip.y.length;
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return c.at(flip.y[columnIndex], rowIndex);
        }

        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return flip.x[columnIndex];
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KxTableModel model = new KxTableModel();
        c c = null;
        try {
            c = new c("localhost", 5001,":");
            String query="select sum amount by city from tab";
//          String query="0!select last price by sym from trade where date=last date";
            model.setFlip((c.Flip) c.k(query));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {try{c.close();} catch (IOException ex) {}
          }
        }
        System.out.println(model.getRowCount());
        System.out.println(model.getValueAt(1, 1));

    }
}
```

The above code gave me the following error after execution :-

```
Apr 14, 2016 9:30:10 AM Aggregate main
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassCastException: kx.c$Dict cannot be cast to kx.c$Flip
    at Aggregate.main(Aggregate.java:40)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Aggregate$KxTableModel.getRowCount(Aggregate.java:17)
    at Aggregate.main(Aggregate.java:47)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your query returns a keyed table (because of the `by city`)
You can now either deal with the `c.Dict` or insert `0!` before your select to unkey the table.

`0!select sum amount by city from tab`

Comment: Thanks hellomichibye. That worked. But how can I handle keyed table(s) in KDB using Java, without unkeying it ? I mean, is there any other way too ?

Comment: final Object res = c.k(query);if (res instanceof c.Dict) {
   final c.Dict dict = (c.Dict) res;
   if ((dict.x instanceof c.Flip) && (dict.y instanceof c.Flip)) {
    final c.Flip key = (c.Flip) dict.x;
    final c.Flip data = (c.Flip) dict.y;
    // do something
   }
  }

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, when I checked the connection details, I found that I was querying to the wrong server. Make sure you're connecting to the right server.